# Sleep Time is not working in Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

Statement: While using `Start-Sleep` for more than `60 min` failing .

Original YML File,

```
trigger:
- none

pool: 'Self-Hosted Windows'

schedules:
  - cron: "00 22 * * 6"
    displayName: Weekly Test Run
    branches:
      include:
      - master
    always: true

steps:
  - script: echo Smoke test started on test environment!!!
    displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      filePath: 'TestAutomation/LoadAgents/startAgentSystem.ps1'
    condition: always()
    displayName: 'Start Auto Test Agent Machin'

  - powershell: |
      Start-Sleep -Second 240
    displayName: 'Pause'

  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      filePath: 'TestAutomation/startSmokeTest.ps1'
    condition: always()
    displayName: 'Smoke Automation Test Started'

  - powershell: |
      Start-Sleep -Second 4200
    displayName: 'Pause'
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      filePath: 'TestAutomation/LoadAgents/stopAgentSystem.ps1'
    condition: always()
    displayName: 'Stop Auto Test Agent Machine'

  - script: 
      echo " Smoke Test Finished !!! "
    displayName: 'Finish'
```

The above is failing with message,

```
The job running on agent prd-agent000A2E ran longer than the maximum time of 60 minutes. For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077134

The operation was canceled.
Pause
```

So I changed and altered the YML file,

```
trigger:
- none

pool: 'Self-Hosted Windows'


schedules:
  - cron: "00 22 * * 6"
    displayName: Weekly Test Run
    branches:
      include:
      - master
    always: true

jobs:
- job: "SmokeTestForSaturday"
  timeoutInMinutes: 180

  steps:
  - script: echo Smoke test started on test environment !!!
    displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      filePath: 'TestAutomation/LoadAgents/startAgentSystem.ps1'
    condition: always()
    displayName: 'Start Auto Test Agent Machine'

  - powershell: |
      Start-Sleep -Second 240
    displayName: 'Pause'

  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      filePath: 'TestAutomation/startSmokeTest.ps1'
    condition: always()
    displayName: 'Smoke Automation Test Started'

  - powershell: |
      Start-Sleep -Second 4200
    displayName: 'Pause'
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      filePath: 'TestAutomation/LoadAgents/stopAgentSystem.ps1'
    condition: always()
    displayName: 'Stop Auto Test Agent Machine'

  - script: 
      echo " Smoke Test Finished !!! "
    displayName: 'Finish'
```

The above is failing with message `##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.` because the `Start-Sleep -Second 4200` never triggered rather `TestAutomation/LoadAgents/stopAgentSystem.ps1` triggered which made `'TestAutomation/startSmokeTest.ps1'` this fail. How to solve this issue ?

Comment: In your ```jobs```, replace ```timeoutInMinutes``` to **120** to allows you to specify the maximum time for a job to run before it is automatically cancelled.

Comment: 1. Would you please help clarify what you mean by "Start-Sleep -Second 4200 never triggered"? Is the PowerShell task running `Start-Sleep -Second 4200` not run? Or has this task already been run and completed? 2. At which step did you see the error message above? 3. Please set `timeoutInMinutes: 0` in your pipeline and check what's the result.

Comment: Yeah , Start-Sleep -Second 4200 not run. And the next step ran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seconds parameter of `Start-Sleep` is "-Second**s**" not "-Second".

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7.4#-seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Please add your run logs. However, if `Start Auto Test Agent Machine` is failed the `Pause` steps never run because they have a default condition. You may try to add `condition: always()` to them:

```
 - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      filePath: 'TestAutomation/LoadAgents/startAgentSystem.ps1'
    condition: always()
    displayName: 'Start Auto Test Agent Machine'

  - powershell: |
      Start-Sleep -Second 240
    condition: always()
    displayName: 'Pause'
```